# Is this a Python 3 bug on str.format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-3.2

```
sqlstring = 'INSERT INTO {}'
table = 'Product'
sqlstring.format(table)
```

does not result to 'INSERT INTO Product' but still 'INSERT INTO {}' why is this so?

Comment: Using my Python 3.2 it does result in "INSERT INTO Product", not sure what the problem is on your side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3.2 does this correctly:

```
$ python3.2
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 22:09:30) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sqlstring = 'INSERT INTO {}'
>>> table = 'Product'
>>> sqlstring.format(table)
'INSERT INTO Product'
>>>
```

What version are you using?

**Additional thought:**

Strings are immutable and do not self-modify in-place.  Maybe you want:

```
sqlstring = sqlstring.format(table)
```

If format strings self-modified themselves in place it would be quite annoying for Python programmers, as each format string could only be used once. Sometimes we want the chance to build a nice format string then use it hundreds of times — which is easy if `format()` returns the result instead of modifying the format in-place.

Comment: python 3.2 r32:88445 Feb 11, 2011 I am using Windows 7 64x

Comment: try putting it in a method then run it.

Comment: What are you doing with the value returned by `format()`?  Are you using it immediately, or does your method save the value somewhere for you to find later?

Answer (score 5):

`format` doesn't modify the string (it can't because strings are immutable). It returns a new string. You need to assign the result of the call to format:

```
result = sqlstring.format(table)
```